# is this single machine batching problem even solveable in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I am currently trying to implement a practical problem for my seminar thesis and don't know how to implement it correctly into Cplex. This is a screenshot of the excel sheet i have to work with. There orders for the next 2 years can be seen. those orders have to be put on a single machine. The machine is like a production drum with four equal quarts. Those quarters have different capacities for different set up groups. Line 2 for example the quarter capacity is 15 for this set up group which means if 17 are required as can be seen the first quadrant is full 15/15 and the second quadrant 02/15, third and fourth quarter are empty. now the task is to find other orders which the same set up group to batch them together in order to increase utilization of this machine.

One special thing is also that orders with the same set up group and same capacity consumption can be put together in one quarter. if the set up group is the same but the capacity consumption is different (because different size in real life) the bigger/smaller sized orders have to be put in a new quarter.

For me it seems like a modified bin packing problem. In Python, I solved it already as it is easier there to use an own heuristic. I don't know how to put this into a mathematical formulation

[Data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYuM8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at the various examples that ship with CPLEX. They include scheduling and packing examples.

A simple approach would be to have a binary decision that is indexed by orders and quarters and is 1 if and only if an order is started in this quarter. Then add a constraint that each order starts in exactly one quarter and add constraints that forbid overlap of orders, forbid two orders of different types to be in the same quarter etc.

Comment: Do you have a link where i can find code examples for scheduling and packing with cplex... tried to google it but no results

Comment: Those come with the CPLEX installation. If you have CPLEX installed then you should have those examples. They are also explained in the online documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_home.html. Or do you use `docplex`?

Comment: what do you think about solving it with bin packing? i solved it like that in python

Comment: If you solved it as bin packing problem in Python then I don't see a reason why it should not work in OPL or docplex. You just have to translate the underlying model.

Comment: ok i will try my best and see how far i get, for the moment  i first need to write the MILP on paper :) i will keep you posted. in python i solved it via a heuristic procedure...